# Log Jenkins Console Output to S3

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-2

So i have to Log my Jenkins Job Console Output to S3 Bucket and this involves many jobs to be configured in a way such that the console output log of the Jenkins job is pushed to S3 post build.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to simply upload logs file to s3 using AWS CLI. You can try below approach.

```
echo "hello from job"
echo "job logs to s3"

cat ${JENKINS_HOME}/jobs/${JOB_NAME}/builds/${BUILD_NUMBER}/log >> ${BUILD_NUMBER}.log

/usr/bin/aws s3 cp  ${BUILD_NUMBER}.log s3://s3_bucket_name/${BUILD_NUMBER}.log
```

[image]

Or you can set cron job to sync local logs folder with s3.

for example, you can set cron job that will run every minutes and sync local log file to s3 or copy and have versioning on s3 side, or the other option is to trigger cronjob script after completion of each job.

```
for logs_file in $(ls /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/*/builds/lastSuccessfulBuild/log); 
#now logs_file contain all job logs file path


do  
   echo "copy logs file to s3 $logs_file
   # to identify file unique
   s3_file_name=$(date +'%Y%-m%d%s')
   aws s3 cp  $logs_file s3://s3_bucket_name/"${s3_file_name}".log
done

#Note there are different directories you can copy accordingly
#lastFailedBuild
#lastSuccessfulBuild
# lastUnstableBuild
#lastUnsuccessfulBuild
# and logs by build numbers
```

Comment: Hey @Adiii Thanks for the input but what if i need to apply the same on atleast 100+ Jobs

Comment: you mean an old job or you want to configure for other similar jobs too?

Comment: Other similar jobs and old jobs too

Comment: you can check the update script and change it accordingly, for the old job you need `$(ls /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/*/builds/*/log);`

Comment: Hey @Adii how can i add a timestamp value to  my log file in groovy when i actually create the plan file before pushing it to the s3.

Comment: `Add timestamps to the Console Output` you can find this option under *Build Environment*

Answer (score 0):

See `tee` in [Utility steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#tee-tee-output-to-file):

```
script {
    tee("$WORKSPACE/my_output.txt") {
       sh "echo Hello"
    }
}
```

You may then upload the results to s3:

```
def path = env.JOB_NAME.replace('%2F','-').replace('/', "-").replace('_', "-").toLowerCase()

withAWS(endpointUrl:"...", credentials:"...") {
  s3Upload bucket: "jenkins",
    path:"${path}/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/",
    file: "my_output.txt",
    workingDir: "${env.WORKSPACE}"
}
```